# How to implement custom URL handler to access JS modal content?

Tags: javascript, url-rewriting

I maintain a wordpress site that is javascript heavy and includes a lot of content in modals created with the the Tingle Modal library. The site is designed as a single-column site for the main page, with hash based navigation to take users up and down the page. What I would like to achieve, is to make the modal content accessible by url, so that external users can be directed to the content.

The modals themselves pull in info from a custom content type and are triggered by a jquery function called by clicking a url on the mainpage. I assume to get the functionality I want I would need to implement some sort of custom URL handler which would trigger the modal function submission, but I'm not sure what the best way to implement this would be ( .htaccess, PHP script, Jquery, combination?). Anyway, I wanted to know if anyone has dealt with something like this and had suggestions?

Comment: Can you share the site URL?

Comment: site is www.greentec-capital.com, the modals are on the team and advisors sections.

Comment: You could hook into [admin-ajax.php](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/javascript/ajax/) or create a custom [REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/).

Comment: I'm guessing this got down-voted because it's not considered WP-enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with javascript, the following logic:

- On page load check if a hash exist in the url with something like:

`var hash = decodeURIComponent(location.hash.substr(1));`

- Then you would have two tables (one for team and one for advisors) with names matching the urls of your modals (e.g.: https://greentec-capital.com/team/peter-grouev/) like:

`var teamHashes = ['peter-grouev', 'erick-yong'];`

- After that you will check if the `hash` is inside of one of your tables*:

`if teamHashes.indexOf(hash) !== -1 { //show modal logic }`

*if `hash` not in `teamHashes` table, then check the `advisorsHashes` table.

Now inside the above `if`, to show the modal, we need to declare the `$modal` like in your code and construct the url and make the ajax call to it, like:

```
if teamHashes.indexOf(hash) !== -1 {
    var $teamModal = new tingle.modal({
        footer: true,
        stickyFooter: false,
        closeMethods: ['overlay', 'escape'],
        closeLabel: "Close",
        cssClass: ['team-modal'],
        onOpen: function() {
            console.log('modal open');
        },
        onClose: function() {
            console.log('modal closed');
            $modal.setContent("");
        },

    var teamUrl = "https://greentec-capital.com/team/"+hash+"/";

    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: teamUrl,
           data: {},
           success: function(result){
               $modal.setContent(result);
               $modal.open();
           }
        });
});
```

That should do it.

Comment: Appreciate the detailed answer, wow, you even included the tingle modal syntax, which is above and beyond what I would have expected!!!!

Comment: just took it from your code :) glad it helped.

Comment: well, you provided the "how" part of the question, I generally knew what had to happen, but it was outside of the range of my familiarity. I always appreciate the extra step. Many mahalos.